# Rebuild existing EC2 instance from snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, snapshot

I have an existing linux EC2 instance with a corrupted root volume.  I have a snapshot of the root that is not corrupted.   Is it possible with terraform to rebuild the instance based on the snapshot ID of the snapshot ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible, this simple configuration should do the job:

```
resource "aws_ami" "aws_ami_name" {
name = "aws_ami_name"
virtualization_type = "hvm"
root_device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs_block_device {
        snapshot_id = "snapshot_ID”
        device_name = "/dev/sda1"
        volume_type = "gp2"
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_name" {
    ami = "${aws_ami.aws_ami_name.id}"
    instance_type = "t3.large"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not really a Terraform-type task, since you're not deploying new infrastructure.

Instead, do it manually:

- Create a **new EBS Volume** from the Snapshot
- **Stop** the instance
- **Detach** the existing root volume (make a note of the device identifier such as `/dev/sda1`)
- **Attach** the new Volume with the same identifier
- **Start** the instance